# how to change tinyMCE Directionality after it has been set

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to change the directionality of tinyMCE on dropdown change :

```
    $('.ddlLanguage').change(function () {
        setLanguage();
    });
    function setLanguage() {
        var lang = $('.ddlLanguage').val()
        if ((lang == "En") || (lang == "Ru") || (lang == "Tr")) {
            tinymce.settings['directionality'] = 'ltr';
        };
        if ((lang == "Ar") || (lang == "Fa")) {
            tinymce.settings['directionality'] = 'rtl';
        };
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
            setLanguage();
    });
```

It sets directionality on page load, but it doesn't change it after first time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd removed and initiated it again and it solved my problem :

```
      function tinyInit(tinyDir) {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: ".txaContent",
                theme: "modern",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
                ],
                toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | ltr rtl",
                image_advtab: true,
                directionality: tinyDir
     };

     function setLanguage() {
        var lang = $('.ddlLanguage').val()
        if ((lang == "En") || (lang == "Ru") || (lang == "Tr")) {
            tinymce.remove();
            tinyInit("ltr");
        };
        if ((lang == "Ar") || (lang == "Fa")) {
            tinymce.remove();
            tinyInit("rtl");
        };
    };
```